# Nature of Photons & electromagnetic spectrum

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, mass

Since photons are massless, how are they considered as particles? Are there similar particles for the range of electromagnetic spectrum?

Comment: The train of thought here is unclear to me - what has the property of having mass or not to do with whether or not we consider them as "particles"? Also, the question about the "range of electromagnetic spectrum" is both unrelated and unclear - are you somehow under the impression that photons are only the quanta of *visible* light?

Answer (score 1):

Photons are the force carriers for the electromagnetic interaction so there are no other similar particles for the electromagnetic force: The photon is the one for the EM interaction. There are, however, other similar particles for the other forces but they are all massive (except for the graviton, the hypothetical force carrier of the gravitational interaction).

In what refers the original question: How are they considered particles?

Here we have to think in what quantum field theory tells us: all particles are seen as localized excitations of the field corresponding to this particle. Therefore photons are particles since they are quantized excitations of electromagnetic modes.

Being massive or not does not have any relation with being a particle, it has a relation with how this particle interacts with the Higgs field.

Answer (score 0):

> Since photons are massless, how are they considered as particles?

This is the table of elementary particles  of the [standard model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) and it includes the photon.

[image: elempart]

It also includes the gluon, carrier of the strong force, which is also massless. The current theory predics that at energies of s[ymmetry breaking of the electroweak interaction](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) the W and Z will also be massless. So massless particles exist in the framework of elementary particles.

> Are there similar particles for the range of electromagnetic spectrum

[Here is the range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) of the electromagnetic spectrum, of which only a tiny part is in the visible light frequencies. **All** classical electromagnetic waves are built up by photons following quantum mechanical rules. The mathematical framework of classical electromagnetic radiation [emerges naturally from the quantum mechanical framework of quantum field theory](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html).

Comment: Thanks everyone. The information is clear. I had thought that photons are only for visible light